# Select distinct on one column get one row

Tags: select, distinct, impala

I have below table A

```
Empl_id Add_type    Ph_no

66      H         44-14424
66      F         44-1442
66      C         67-384-295
66      B         (8888) 8440
66      H         608 6775
57      B         12345
57      C         78910
58      C         9988
```

I need to get distinct emp_id and phone_number where if Address =B  then ph_number else null as phone_number

my output should be as below where SQL picks Add_type as B and pulls ph_no else shows null

```
Empl_id      Ph_no
66           (8888) 8440
57           12345
58           NULL
```

I have tried below query:

```
select distinct y.emp_id, case when Add_type='B' then i.iphone else null end  
ip from (SELECT empl_id,Add_type as phty,ph_no as ph,Row_number() 
OVER(PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY employee_id) rn 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT 
E.empl_id,E.Add_type,E.ph_no FROM Table Emp E )t )y 
left outer join 
(SELECT 
e1.empl_id,Add_type,E1.ph_no, case when Add_type='B' then ph_no else null 
end phone 
FROM Table Emp E1 
group by E1.employee_id, Address, 
E1.phone_number )i 
on y.empl_id=i.empl_id 
WHERE y.rn = 1 and i.emp_id='66'
```

The output I get of above query is

```
emp_id  ph
66     (8888) 8440
66     NULL
```

I get 2 rows, I need to have one with the ph_no. Where am I doing it wrong? I am using Impala as my DB.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: My sincere apologies for mentioning"urgently" . I have already tried getting solution for problem for last 3 days. Only after having failed at that have I posted it on the forum

Comment: You are welcome to post it once you have thoroughly researched it after half a day - you don't need to wait until it really is urgent to post. Nevertheless, we don't care if it is urgent, since volunteers are rarely willing to provide priority answers. You may even find that asking for special treatment will result in downvotes, and then you'll be even less likely to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give you your desired output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
empl_id
, ph_num
from
  (
    SELECT
    empl_id
    , add_type
    , CASE 
      WHEN add_type = 'B' 
      THEN ph_num
      ELSE NULL
      END AS ph_num
    FROM table
  ) t1
```